# Есть ли речевая ошибка?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Разобраться в этих вопросах - значит раскрыть проблему произведения автора - уникальности человека и человеческой души.

Где-то видел, что при уточнении / пояснении слово может опускаться, т.е:

> Разобраться в этих вопросах - значит раскрыть проблему произведения автора - (проблему) уникальности человека и человеческой души.

Так ли это на самом деле? Допустимо ли это и считается ли какой-то ошибкой?